# Настройка devServer

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь настроить devServer, но что-то пошло не так в какой-то момент.
**Архитектура:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Webpack**

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'distribution'),
    openPage: 'templates/index.html',
    port: 9000
},
```

**Консоль:**

```
$ webpack-dev-server --watch --open --mode development
i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:9000/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /distribution/
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from E:\Oasis_apps\oasis\assets\javascript\application\distribution
i ｢wdm｣: Hash: d5dd1f9cbcd21555bee9
Version: webpack 4.43.0
Time: 4853ms
Built at: 2020-05-04 10:40:16
```

**Результат:**

> Cannot GET /templates/index.html

Мне кажется я на правильном пути, но все же пока оно не работает :с Помогите пж.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Исправил, теперь выглядит получше.

Comment: настройку entry point Тоже добавь